# how can i disable toad for oracle's blue lines in editor?

Tags: oracle11g, toad

i am writing a function or store procedure with if and else if Toad shows blue lines under codes and show messages about using select case instead of if statement,how can i disable it?

Answer (score 3):

Under the TOAD Options form, select Code Analysis/General, and uncheck the checkbox at the top labelled, "Check rules as you type."